# iOS Deployment Target for Universal App

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Good morning, stackoverflow folks.

I'm having a small problem, and I can't find a **solid** answer via google, stackoverflow, or from the Apple documentation. Perhaps I am not searching for the right keywords. Anywho, on with my simple, stupid question(s):

I'm currently developing a universal app. **I'd like for the iOS Deployment Target to be set for 3.2+ for the iPad, and 4.0+ for iPhone/iPod Touch**, yet there is only one field for the setting. Should I be setting this value to 3.2 or 4.0? Isn't 3.2 an iPad-only SDK? Does this value need to be set in **both** the Project Build Settings and the Target Build Settings?

Please note: I'm using **'Latest iOS (currently set to 4.2)'** as the Base SDK, and after reading the following, I still can't derive a definitive answer:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Configuring/configuring.html

Any help in the matter would be greatly appreciated.Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set Base SDK to the latest, and set Deployment Target to 3.2.  *THEN*––and this is important––if you use any API that is available ONLY in 4.0 or later (that is, NOT in 3.2), then you must do a runtime check to see if that API is actually available, and if not, do something else.

Comment: Randall, Thank you for the swift reply. I've had the deployment target set to 3.2 all along, and the app works swimmingly on all of my test devices (iPad 3.2, iPhone4 4.1, and iPhone3G 4.1) and in the simulator. With regards to your comment, as long as everything is working as it should, do I still need to do this runtime check? I am using the if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM) conditional in a few places in my code. Is doing this sufficient, or should I be doing something else? I've read 'Using SDK-Based Development' and 'Configuring a Project for SDK-Based Development' in-depth, and am struggling.

Comment: All UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM tells you is whether you're running on iPhone/iPod or iPad, not the OS version.  If you attempt to call a 4.x-only API when running on 3.2, you *will* crash.  You only have to make the runtime check if you call *any* 4.x-only API (since that is not available at runtime on 3.2).